# SpringBootApplication with log4j2 throws error on start

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I configured my log4j2.yml with properties from springboot:

```
Properties:
    property:
      - name: LOGSTASH_HOST
        value: ${spring:logstash.server.host}
      - name: LOGSTASH_PORT
        value: ${spring:logstash.server.port}
      - name: APPLICATION_NAME
        value: ${lower:${spring:spring.application.name:-spring}}
```

If I start my application I get a bunch of error messages saying:

ERROR StatusConsoleListener Resolver failed to lookup spring:logstash.server.host
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to obtain Spring Environment from LoggerContext

and

ERROR StatusConsoleListener Unable to write to stream TCP:localhost:9800 for appender LOGSTASH
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:localhost:9800: socket not available at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:214)

It can not find the serverhost until springboot starts which takes a few seconds, after that the logging works fine and no more error messages.

How could I configure my log4J2 to start after or when springboot starts and don't spam error messages.

I've tried excluding the springr boot starter logging in pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

or I've tried fallback hosts and ports:

```
Properties:
  property:
    - name: LOGSTASH_HOST
      value: "${sys:LOGSTASH_HOST:-${env:LOGSTASH_HOST:-localhost}}" # Prefer system property, then env variable, fallback to 'localhost'
    - name: LOGSTASH_PORT
      value: "${sys:LOGSTASH_PORT:-${env:LOGSTASH_PORT:-5044}}" # Prefer system property, then env variable, fallback to '5044'
    - name: APPLICATION_NAME
      value: "${sys:spring.application.name:-${env:spring_application_name:-default-application}}" # System property, env variable, fallback
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your log4j2.yml file to **log4j2-spring.yml**
This is one possibility described in the documentation since 3.0.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.4/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log4j2-extensions

> Because the standard log4j2.xml configuration file is loaded too early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use log4j2-spring.xml or define a logging.config property.